# Changing 'voiceReceiveMode' to fax is not working

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

Using Twilio, I am trying to buy a Fax number and set its webhooks accordingly.

```
$number = $twilio->incomingPhoneNumbers
       ->create([
             "voiceReceiveMode" => 'fax', 

             // also tried "VoiceReceiveMode" => 'fax',

             "voiceUrl" => "http://example.com",
             "phoneNumber" => $request->number,
             "voiceMethod" => "POST"
      ]
);
```

With this code, I am able to purchase the number, set voice method to post also sets the voice url.

---

I have set the voiceUrl because in the Docs it says:

> "At this point, the number's VoiceUrl will now behave as its FaxUrl". [as mentioned here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/fax/receive#phone-number-setup)

However `voiceReveiveMode` doesn't change and always stays at "Voice"

Also, if I `dd($number)`, in IncomingPhoneNumberInstance object, under properties, I don't see `voiceReceiveMode`

```
IncomingPhoneNumberInstance {#249 ▼
  #_assignedAddOns: null
  #version: V2010 {#244 ▶}
  #context: null
  #properties: array:30 [▼
    "accountSid" => "**"
    "addressSid" => null
    "addressRequirements" => "none"
    "apiVersion" => "2010-04-01"
    "beta" => false
    "capabilities" => array:4 [▶]
    "dateCreated" => DateTime {#250 ▶}
    "dateUpdated" => DateTime {#251 ▶}
    "friendlyName" => "(218) 963-5608"
    "identitySid" => null
    "phoneNumber" => "+12189635608"
    "origin" => "twilio"
    "sid" => "**"
    "smsApplicationSid" => ""
    "smsFallbackMethod" => "POST"
    "smsFallbackUrl" => ""
    "smsMethod" => "POST"
    "smsUrl" => ""
    "statusCallback" => ""
    "statusCallbackMethod" => "POST"
    "trunkSid" => null
    "uri" => "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACcc7e0c85b66b0414485f08a1e03abdba/IncomingPhoneNumbers/PNe2bd51168e719b86cee6c9c46074e46c.json"
    "voiceApplicationSid" => null
    "voiceCallerIdLookup" => false
    "voiceFallbackMethod" => "POST"
    "voiceFallbackUrl" => null
    "voiceMethod" => "POST"
    "voiceUrl" => "http://example.app"
    "emergencyStatus" => "Inactive"
    "emergencyAddressSid" => null
  ]
```

Comment: What version of Twilio-PHP are you using?

Comment: @philnash sdk 5.16? Is it the correct one?

Comment: Hmm, `voiceReceiveMode` was added in version 5.13.2. Are you sure you're up to date?

Comment: Yes, I have just pulled the this week. In my composer.json it is `"twilio/sdk": "^5.16"`

Comment: Ok, cool. Did you ensure that the number was fax capable before you bought it? Are you able to update the number and change it to "fax" mode using the API? (Sorry for all the questions, sounds like you're doing the right thing, I'm just trying to find where the bug is!)

Comment: @philnash Yes, I can confirm it is fax-capable (while searching for the number, I search explicitly for fax-enabled; and also, now I can confirm from Console too that it's fax-capable. Secondly, I can change it to fax mode using Console, but i didn't try to change it with a separate api call - only while purchasing (like I showed above). If you use the above code, does it work for you properly? Do I need to add any other fields in my POST array?

Comment: Thanks for investigating. Turns out it's not your fault at all and the issue is with us. Please check out my answer. Hope that's ok for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

After speaking with the Fax team at Twilio it turns out that currently you cannot set the `VoiceReceiveMode` for a phone number at the time of purchase. Technically this is a limitation in the PHP library for allowing you to try to set that parameter (I tried in Ruby and it wasn't possible). However, ultimately it's a bug in the API for not allowing this.

For now, I recommend that you use another API call to update the number's `VoiceReceiveMode` once you have bought it and have its SID.

At the same time we are looking into updating the API to accept this parameter when you make the purchase. I will endeavour to update this answer when we ship that.

Comment: Thanks for looking it up. I'll be waiting for your answer and solve it with the workaround. Also that'd be great if you can make this feature testable with test credentials as it's costing ~$1 per each try